# Checkbox check updating multiple cells of the same value

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, formula, google-sheets-formula

Here is the what my Google Sheet looks like (placeholder data) -

[image]

Right now, now when I check a checkbox it highlights the checkbox cell and the Order Reference cell in the same row, like so:

[image]

This is achieved with this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($Y2:Y2, "=TRUE")
```

on this range

```
A2:A999,Y2:Y999
```

However, I want all of the same "Order References" to also be highlight from a single checkbox. For example, in the above image, the 2nd "1002" should also be highlighted when the checkbox in the same row as the first "1002" has been checked.

It is also important to notice that not all "Order Reference" come in twos, for example "1005" and "1007" only appear once. So a check against the cell below wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- custom formula for rule 1: **`=COUNTIF($Y2, "=TRUE")`** for range **A2:A,Y2:Y**
- custom formula for rule 2: **`=AND($Y2=TRUE, ISBLANK($Y3), $A2=$A3)`** for range **A3:A**

[image]

Comment: However, I have an issue. It works great with the current data, but it doesn't to seem to be expandable and/or flexible. For example, if the data is different - Order "1002" appearance only once or the second "1002" is removed, or the first order number appearance only once at the top. It doesn't seem to work, any ideas on how to make it work with any data of any amounts (up to 10 of the same order references, preferably).

Comment: For example, - http://prntscr.com/mh0o4u It is okay to have checkboxes all the way down, as long as they are grouped and highlighted green with the same amount of "Reference Number". Thank you!

Comment: @wanderwanderer https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NOCikpN4Q-pYlPJ56PnjpcevaQRl5nu9K2D_PtL442E/edit#gid=0